# How do i unregister a CXF endpoint programatically

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I am having some trouble getting my head around a facet of CXF. While some people might say "Just try it and see" CXF is such a massive beast that i would rather avoid nasty surprises down the line, thus the question:

I see that it is possible to register an endpoint as seen in the documentation:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-ConfiguringJAX-RSendpointsprogrammaticallywithoutSpring

But if I need to stop the server again, do i have to do anything more than invoke [Server.Stop()](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/endpoint/Server.html#stop())?

And how would i go about only removing the endpoint(The resource class) from the server, assuming i have other endpoints on the same server that I don't wish to stop?

Comment: Does https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf/blob/master/src/main/java/com/skjolberg/mockito/soap/SoapServerRule.java help?

Comment: It does a little bit. I will have to look into what role a destination has.